# Centos php 5.3.1

Tags: php, centos

I have installed the php 5.3.6
In the terminal, the php version is 5.3.6 by entering the command php -v. 
However, in the website, it show it is 5.1.6 by using phpinfo.

What is the problem??

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
yum list installed | grep php
```

You most likely have installed a new version of php53-cli, but are still running the older version of php.  Simply install the php53 base and that will get them in sync.

Alternatively you may have installed the new version of php, but have not yet restarted your apache, if that is the case you simply need to:

```
service httpd restart
```

Answer (score 0):

What command did You use to install php 5.3.6 in terminal ?? Maybe You used yum install php-cli - if so this is only command line version of php.